# Ionic 2 : Use picture in tab button

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs, ionic2

I use ion-tabs in my App and I want to use an picture in a tab-button. 
I want to set this picture dynamicly.

In my case, I have an account with different users linked to it. I want to change my tab picture depending of the selected user.

I have this :

[image]

And i want this :

[image]

My code in my tabs :

```
    <ion-tabs tabsHighlight="false">
      <ion-tab [root]="HomePage" 
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
               tabIcon="checkbox"
               tabTitle="A faire"
               tabBadge="5"
               tabBadgeStyle="notif">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="ToComePage"
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
               tabIcon="time" tabTitle="A venir"
               tabBadge="0"
               tabBadgeStyle="notif">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="HistoricPage"
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
               tabIcon="book"
               tabTitle="Historique">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="MenuPage"
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
//I want to delete this tab Icon and replace it by a picture.
               tabIcon="menu"
               tabTitle="Menu">
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

I don't know how to do that, an idea ?

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you tried.

Comment: I changed my post. I don't know what do you need to understand better what I want to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I find a solution ! 
I just write in the created DOM.

I do like this :

```
updateAccountTab() : void {
      let array = document.getElementsByClassName('tabbar');
      let tabbar = array[0];
      let element = tabbar.childNodes[tabbar.childElementCount-1];
      if(element) {
          element.removeChild(element.childNodes[1]);
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.setAttribute("class", "tab-icon-custom tab-button-icon icon icon-md");
          img.setAttribute("src", this.pdata.user.profile_thumbnail);
          element.insertBefore(img, element.childNodes[1]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: That's not the recommended way to interact with the DOM in Angular / Ionic apps. It may lead to some performance issues.

Comment: Sure, I understand. But I didn't find another way to do what I want ...

Comment: Oh, ok. Later today I'll edit your answer and include the _ionic way_ to do exactly the same :)

Comment: Oh I look forward to that ! :D It will be perfect. ^^

Comment: @sebaferreras Did you find a "Ionic way" of doing this?

Answer (score 13):

give custom name to `tabIcon` like

```
<ion-tab [root]="MenuPage"
       tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
       tabIcon="customicon"
       tabTitle="Menu">
</ion-tab>
```

and in css:

```
.ion-ios-customicon-outline,
.ion-ios-customicon,.ion-md-customicon,.ion-md-customicon-outline {
  content: url('imageurl');
}
```

[plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/9eHeKjNmlTnUpNv2OZe4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks it works ! But how can I change the size of the picture ? I tried to modify width but it's not efective.

Comment: How can I dynamically change the picture URL ?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to change the picture url?

Comment: Anyone did it? how to change picture url ( dynamically )

Comment: I found a solution if you want.

Comment: just post the solution here

Comment: @V.Pivet ping 15char

Answer (score 0):

In Your html :

```
<ion-tabs tabsHighlight="false" #myTab>
      <ion-tab [root]="HomePage" 
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
               tabIcon="checkbox"
               tabTitle="A faire"
               tabBadge="5"
               tabBadgeStyle="notif">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="ToComePage"
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
               tabIcon="time" tabTitle="A venir"
               tabBadge="0"
               tabBadgeStyle="notif">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="HistoricPage"
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
               tabIcon="book"
               tabTitle="Historique">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="MenuPage"
               tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
//I want to delete this tab Icon and replace it by a picture.
               tabIcon="menu"
               tabTitle="Menu">
      </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

In your component (ts) file :

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {Tabs} from 'ionic-angular';
export class TabsPage {

  @ViewChild('myTab') tabRef: Tabs;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let tabbar = this.tabRef._tabbar.nativeElement;
    let element = tabbar.childNodes[tabbar.childElementCount-1];
    if(element) {
      element.removeChild(element.childNodes[1]);
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.setAttribute("class", "tab-icon-custom");
      img.setAttribute("src", 'https://picsum.photos/200');
      element.insertBefore(img, element.childNodes[1]);
    }

  }
}
```

In your scss file :

```
.tab-icon-custom {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```